# Need assistance C++ compiler and linker error messages

Tags: c++

I've been working on program for my assignment for college and I'm almost done but I got this strange error,and simply can't find solution anywhere. This is just one function from program.So...it throws an error on this part of code. XOR operator seems to be the problem. I have tried to rename name of "nesto" variable in case it is the same as name of some function but with no success. Please Help! Ideas ? Suggestions ?

**error: no match for call to ‘(std::string {aka std::basic_string}) (int&)’**

```
void* ukupno(void* naziv){
    while(kraj!=1){
        sem_wait(&s_suma);
        for(int v=0;v<uk_buffer;v++) 
                nesto^= buffer(v);

        sem_post(&s_dohvati);   
        }
    }
```

here is entire code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

using namespace std;
bool zastavica=1,kraj;
int uk_buffer,broj=0,nesto=0;
string buffer;


sem_t s_dohvati;
sem_t s_broji_rijeci;
sem_t s_suma;


void otvori_dat(string naziv){
    fstream dat;
    cout<<"naziv   " << naziv << endl;
    dat.open("naziv",ios::in);  
    }

void* dohvati(void* naziv){

    fstream dat;
    dat.open((char*)naziv,ios::in);
    if(!dat){
            cout<<"Greska kod otvaranja datoteke !!! " << endl;
            exit(-1);}
    kraj = false;
    while(!kraj){
                getline(dat,buffer);
                uk_buffer = buffer.length();
                if(dat.eof()) kraj = true;

                sem_post(&s_broji_rijeci);
                sem_post(&s_suma);

    if(kraj) sem_wait(&s_dohvati),sem_wait(&s_dohvati);
    }                               
    dat.close();
    }

void broji_txt(){ 
            for(int i=0;i<uk_buffer;i++)
                  if(isalnum(buffer[i])){
                        broj++;
                        while(isalnum(buffer[++i]));
                        }
                }        


void broji_html(){  for (int i=1;i<uk_buffer;i++)
                if (buffer[i-1]=='<'&&buffer[i]!='/')
                        broj++;
                        }


void* broji_rijeci(void* naziv){
    while(kraj!=1){
        sem_wait(&s_broji_rijeci);
            if(zastavica) broji_txt();
            else broji_html();
        sem_post(&s_dohvati);//postavljanje
        }
    }

void* ukupno(void* naziv){
    int nesto=0;
    while(kraj!=1){
        sem_wait(&s_suma);
        for(int v=0;v<uk_buffer;v++) 
                nesto^= buffer(v);

        sem_post(&s_dohvati);   
        }
    }

void analiza(char* naziv){
    pthread_t pt_dohvati, pt_broji_rijeci, pt_suma;

    sem_init (&s_dohvati,0,0);
    sem_init (&s_broji_rijeci,0,0);
    sem_init (&s_suma,0,0);

    pthread_create (&pt_dohvati,NULL,dohvati,(void*)naziv);     //zadnji parametar je ono što šaljem;
    pthread_create (&pt_broji_rijeci,NULL,broji_rijeci,NULL);
    pthread_create (&pt_suma, NULL, ukupno, NULL);

    pthread_join(pt_dohvati,NULL);
    pthread_join(pt_broji_rijeci,NULL);
    pthread_join(pt_suma,NULL);
    cout << "Datoteka " << naziv << " ima " << broj << "rijeci/tagova, zastitna suma je: " <<(unsigned int)nesto;
}


int main(int arg0 , char* arg1[]){
    char* pom;
    int br_arg = arg0-1;//po njemu se orijentiramo

    for(int k=1; k<=br_arg;k++){
        pom=strchr(arg1[k],'.');
        if(strcmp(pom,".txt") == 0)             zastavica=1;
        else if(strcmp(pom,".html") == 0)   zastavica=0;
        else cout<< "Datoteka " << arg1[k] << " nije podrzanog formata " <<  endl;
        switch(fork()){
                    case  0 : analiza(arg1[k]),exit(0);
                    case -1 : cerr<< "Pogreska pri stvaranju procesa" << endl;
                    default : continue;
                        }
                                }
            for(int i=0; i < br_arg ;i++)   wait (NULL);        
return 0;
}
```

Comment: And now please the line number for the error...

Comment: yeah,same problem with +,- and other operators...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that there is no way to use the function call syntax if what you've got isn't a function but a string. Instead of `buffer(v)`, you probably meant `buffer[v]`. The type of brackets used matters.

Comment: True ! That is solution but I still can't compile

Comment: How so? Do you get another compiler error?

Comment: tons of "undefined reference to 'sem_post'" for almost every thread create,join and sem_wait/post  and @ the end ofc Id returned 1 exit status

Comment: @LovroPredovan That means you *can* compile, but you cannot *link*. Most likely, the options you're passing to GCC are wrong, see the documentation for `sem_post` and look for "Link with".

Comment: Yeah, my bad...just forgot to raise flags for working with threads in bash   -lpthread -D_REENTRANT did just fine. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough code to say, but this error looks like there is no visible declaration for the

```
buffer(v);
```

**Edit**

Okay.  Now we can see.  Try `buffer[v]`.

Comment: ... so perhaps any of the 5 lines of code

Answer (score 0):

your buffer is string

```
string buffer;
```

so what is

```
nesto^= buffer(v);
```

change buffer to be an array of vector or any other container since you want to index it. If you want a letter from buffer as a single string then do:

```
nesto^= buffer[v];
```